# android button color and save

Tags: android

I wanted to change the android `button` color from black to red. Once a user clicks a button, I want the button become red. Then, when the user exit the app and open it again the button will stay red and the button will not be disabled.

Comment: onClick method change the color

Comment: i need help. pls

Comment: show your code what you have done.

Comment: do you have the code ? using shared preference

Comment: yes I have but what you did show then i will implement

Comment: its too long for 603 characters here i cant send .

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to store button's color on a button click

Comment: @fitnesshealth wait i will share here

Comment: i need it for my thesis im making a fitness and health app. where when i click the button it will change the background color so that the user will know that he finish the day

Comment: i will wait sir . i really need the help . hey sir @NaveenTP do you have a code like that sir ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`SharedPreferences`**

check the below example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("Nilesh", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();

        if (preferences.getString("color", "blcack").equals("red")) {
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
    } else {
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("1D1D27"));
    }


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editor.putString("color", "red");
            editor.commit();
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
        }
    });

    }

}
```

add this colors inside **`res->values->color.xml`** file

```
<color name="red">#8B0000</color>
<color name="black">#1D1D27</color>
```

Comment: ahm sir how to make it , become red permanently when i clicked the button .

Comment: sir . the app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

According to `activity` life cycle use this code as per your requirement
like you said **need it for my thesis im making a fitness and health app. where when i click the button it will change the background color so that the user will know that he finish the day**

In **XML** do like this :-

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:background="#000" />
```

and in your **Java** file do like this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
int color = Color.parseColor("#fc2828");
int myIntValue;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("your_int_key", color);
    editor.commit();


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);

            button.setBackgroundColor(myIntValue);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);

    button.setBackgroundColor(myIntValue);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Copy and paste this code in life cycle(like `onResume`, `onRestart`) methods :-

```
 sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);

    button.setBackgroundColor(myIntValue);
```

Comment: ahm sir where would i see that life cycle method ?

Comment: @fitnesshealth  search on google lifecycle of activity it will show you

Comment: sir why the button become red even if i didint click it ?

Comment: clean and rebuild

Comment: sir ineed a black button background . and when i clicked it it become red . and when i exit the app and reopen it it will become red permanently .

Comment: @fitnesshealth now check i have updated the code and after writing code please clean and rebuild your code then install if it is working give upvote

Comment: sir it becomes red only . iwant a button that is black first and when i clicked it it become red , and when i exit the app and reopen it it will stay red .

Comment: @fitnesshealth yes its having like this in my phone

Comment: how can i resolve it sir ? its not like that when i made it

Comment: @fitnesshealth do you have teamviewer?

Comment: @fitnesshealth share your details on abhinavguptabit@gmail.com

Comment: how can i share it to you sir ?

Comment: send me mail teamviewer id and password  on my mail id :- abhinavguptabit@gmail.com

Comment: i cant connect sir .

Comment: can i contact you via gmail ?

Comment: @fitnesshealth yes you can